# How to find the number of lists in an input? (python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion

```
def lists(A: list) -> int:

    '''Return the total number of lists in A (including A itself).
    Each element of A and any  nested lists are either ints or other lists.

    Example:
    >>> lists([1, 2, 3])
    1
    >>> lists([[1], [2], [3]])
    4
    >>> lists([[[1, 2], [], 3]])
    4
    '''
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
All I have is

```
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    if (isinstance(A[i], list)):
        count=count+1
        return(lists(A[i]))
    else:
        B=A[i:]
return(count)
```

Comment: Why do you create `B`?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Since you're trying to solve this with recursion, what is your base case? What is your recursive step?

Comment: return(lists(A[i])) Is my recursive step, recursion should stop when there is no more elements to be checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a 'dirty' but easy way to do it

```
def lists(l):
    '''
    Return the total number of lists in A (including A itself).
    Each element of A and any  nested lists are either ints or other lists.
    '''

    # convert the list to string and count the ['s
    # each [ is the start of a list, so the number of ['s equals
    # the number of lists
    nr_of_lists = str(l).count('[')

    # return the number of sublists
    return nr_of_lists
```

No recursion required

Comment: What if the list contains strings containing '['?

Comment: @timgeb the docstring states it only contains sublists or ints

Comment: Oh, right, nevermind then. Pretty dirty nonetheless ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to write it:

```
def numlists(lst, num = 1):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            num += numlists(item)
    return num
```

Sample outputs:

```
print(numlists([1, 2, 3])) # 1
print(numlists([[1], [2], [3]])) # 4
print(numlists([[[1, 2], [], 3]])) # 4
print(numlists([[1,[2,3,[4,5,[6]]]],7,8,[9]])) # 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this with recursion:

```
def count_list(a):
    result = 0
    if isinstance(a, list):
        result += 1
    try:
        for b in a:
            result += count_list(b)
    except:
        pass
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lists(A):
    return 1 + sum(lists(e) if isinstance(e, list) else 0 for e in A)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lists(a):

    if not isinstance(a, list):
        return 0

    s = 1

    for x in a:
        s += lists(x)

    return s

print lists([])
print lists([1,2,3])
print lists([[1], [2], [3]])
print lists([[[1, 2], [], 3]])
```